# Android ListView

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I would like to create a custom list view like in the Native Email application

1. When you click the check box you can add a click listner and do a particular action
2. When you long press it opens the contextual Menu
3. When you click the list item it performs another function like going to another activity to display that email kind.

If you can point to the code in the Native Email Application.. it would be great too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is sufficient to post a link to the app you need, here's a link to the source of [Email Application](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Email.git;a=tree).

Other resources you should check out:

- [Hello Views tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)
- [API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html) in the samples folder of Android SDK